# Can't embed with model in Azure AI Studio

Tags: azure, azure-openai, openaiembeddings, azure-ai, azure-ai-search

There's a deployed `text-embedding-ada-002` in my AI Studio project but I can't create indexes with the data and documents uploaded using that deployed embedding model.

Instead, AI Studio uses Serverless compute to generate the index. How can I use the deployed index?

[image: Create an index in AI Studio]

[image: Index created in AI Studio]

Comment: There would be many chances for not creating indexes with your data and documents. If you could share any exceptions that you got it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't create indexes with the data and documents uploaded using that deployed embedding model.

***if dataset is in a correct format, we can run the pipeline successfully please recheck the data and the documents with storage container connected.***

Here I also had deployed with my `text-embedding-ada-002` in the AI studio to create indexes.

[image]

[image]

And now, I can be able to create the indexes as shown in below.

[image]

***Deployment status :***

[image]